# mysql multiple locks, single row

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking

[This article](http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-mysql-innodb-deadlocks-and-duplicate-key-errors-12-1970.html) says:

> ```
>   Tx 1: lock A, then B 
>   Tx 2: lock B, then A
> ```
>
> Because InnoDB starts transactions on the internally, you -are- going
>   to experience deadlocks.
>
> No way of escaping it.

I'm seeing error code 1213 when many threads are trying to insert a row with the same PK, but I don't understand how there could be two locks. Isn't there just the single lock on that row?

Answer (score 0):

If it's `read lock` then there can be more than one since read locks are shared but there can be only one `write lock` at any time. Every DML operation (`insert/update/delete`) will operate on implicit transaction and will hold a row level lock on that row and thus if any other thread trying to perform a write operation on that particular row it has to wait for the existing lock to be released since write locks are exclusive lock.

Scenario you have posted *Tx 1: lock A, then B Tx 2: lock B, then A* will definitely result into `deadlock` and that's why locking happens to in two phase. `Growing phase` when the transaction will acquire all the needed locks to perform the transaction and `Shrinking phase` when it will start releasing locks held by that transaction.